# Gallery of TextViews, using styles etc

Tags: android

I want to use `Gallery` as a horizontal menu so I've taken the code for the [Gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) to use `TextView`s instead of `ImageViews` by using a `String[]` and changing the adapter's `getView((...)` method as follows...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText(mMenuItems[position]);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    return tv;
}
```

The problem I have now is as shown in the image...

[image]

As you can see, what should be the 'selected' `TextView` is 'greyed' (although I can select it) and the other items are 'highlighted and I'd like the reverse. So the question is what is `Gallery` doing to cause this and how do I override it?

UI stuff is a weak point of mine (I'm learning gradually honest) but I think I need to define styles as explained here...[Definining styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles) and I understand what's being explained but how do I get the `Gallery` to automatically apply the styles I define? Do I have to apply the styles the `TextView`s I return from the adapter's `getView(...)` method or can I apply them 'globally' to the `Gallery` somehow?

Comment: You could use a selector to specify the text "options" that you want. As for "globally" changing the `Gallery`, I don't think you can without hacking the os. Selector Resource: http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `getSelectedItemPosition()` to update the view accordingly but you'll need a reference to the Gallery view (`mGallery` below):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
    tv.setText(mMenuItems[position]);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
    if (position == mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
        // set tv properties to make it look selected
    } else {
        // set tv properties to make it look unselected
    }
    return tv;
}
```